# deleting row in SQLite 3

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios4, fmdb

In `UITableView`, I want to delete a row and remove that row on database, but my query of sqlite don't works.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    UIAlertView *view;

    sqlite3 *database;
    int result = sqlite3_open("/quickdatabase.sqlite", &database);
    if(result != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Database Error" message:@"Falha ao carregar o banco de dados.." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [view show];
        [view release];
        return;
    } else {
        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM Enquetes WHERE Pergunta = '%@' AND Nome = '%@'", [arraySQL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [arrayAsk objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        sqlite3_exec(database, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
        sqlite3_close(database);

        view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ArrayAsk" message:[arrayAsk objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [view show];
        [view release];

        view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ArraySQL" message:[arraySQL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [view show];
        [view release];

        [arrayAsk removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [arraySQL removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}   
}
```

Why doesn't this work? 
Where I can see a good tutorial of FMDB framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMDB is here: http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tree/master/src/

The sample you are looking for is also on that page; the sample is "fmdb.m".

Comment: In the example, no have a example about query to delete. Just have to insert, update and create a new table.

Comment: Pass your DELETE to executeUpdate, like the example's INSERT and CREATEs.

Comment: I tryed this and not worked:
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/quickdatabase.db"];
  [db open]
  
  [db setShouldCacheStatements:YES];
  [db executeUpdate:@"delete from Enquetes where Nome = ?", [arrayAsk objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  [db close];
  
  [pool release];
  return 0;

Comment: =[db setShouldCacheStatements:YES]= is experimental, so try without that. At this point I would triple-check the arrayAsk content; try the SQL with a hard-coded value. What exactly is failing? Check for errors Do you have write access to that file? Try adding =FMDBQuickCheck([db hadError]);= to check for errors.

Comment: The problem was in string to delete. Sorry and thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Try FMDB

Download the lib package and take a look in the example file included.